# Storing and Retrieving List of ParseUsers

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In using parse, I'm trying to save an

ArrayList of < ParseUser >

in the 'value' of a 'key' for a specific ParseObject. As per my understanding, this is possible, and I am doing it simply by passing in an ArrayList as the value and calling saveInBackground().

Looks like the save is successful and is stored in the data browser like this:

```
[[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"fHwBwBkLtn"}]]
```

To retrieve this object, looks like when I do `Object.get("array_key")` it seems to return a JSONArray instead of an ArrayList of ParseUsers.

How can I directly parse this (*excuse the pun*) into an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to tell it to include the users in your query, have a look at [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational), there's a section that talks about the include method.

```
query.include("users");
```

Now when you call `resultObject.get("users")` you should get an ArrayList of ParseUser objects.

Comment: I think even in this case, he will get a JSONArray, though it will have full ParseObjects instead of unfetched pointers. JSONArray is what the Parse SDK uses for collections, and it should be trivial to convert to an ArrayList.

Comment: Ah, handy to know, I have only worked with the JavaScript and iOS SDK, not the Android one yet.